# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'userId' of 'req.body' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, postman

Every Time I try to do a post request in postman to *http://localhost:3000/api/orders/new*

I am getting this error:
**TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'userId' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.
    at C:\Users\Web-Developer\Desktop\shoppy\backend\routes\orders.js:70:10
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Web-Developer\Desktop\shoppy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Web-Developer\Desktop\shoppy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Web-Developer\Desktop\shoppy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Web-Developer\Desktop\shoppy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Web-Developer\Desktop\shoppy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Web-Developer\Desktop\shoppy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Web-Developer\Desktop\shoppy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\Web-Developer\Desktop\shoppy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\Web-Developer\Desktop\shoppy\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
**

```
const router = express.Router();
const {database} = require('../config/helpers');

/* GET ALL ORDERS */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    database.table('orders_details as od')
        .join([
            {
                table: 'orders as o',
                on: 'o.id = od.order_id'
            },
            {
                table: 'products as p',
                on: 'p.id = od.product_id'
            },
            {
                table: 'users as u',
                on: 'u.id = o.user_id'
            }
        ])
        .withFields(['o.id', 'p.title as name', 'p.description', 'p.price', 'u.username'])
        .sort({id: 1})
        .getAll()
        .then(orders => {
            if(orders.length > 0) {
                res.status(200).json(orders);
            } else {
                res.json({message: 'Mo Orders Found'})
            }
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
})


/* GET SINGLE ORDER */
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {

    const orderId = req.params.id;

    database.table('orders_details as od')
        .join([
            {
                table: 'orders as o',
                on: 'o.id = od.order_id'
            },
            {
                table: 'products as p',
                on: 'p.id = od.product_id'
            },
            {
                table: 'users as u',
                on: 'u.id = o.user_id'
            }
        ])
        .withFields(['o.id', 'p.title as name', 'p.description', 'p.price', 'u.username'])
        .filter({'o.id': orderId})
        .getAll()
        .then(orders => {
            if(orders.length > 0) {
                res.status(200).json(orders);
            } else {
                res.json({message: `No Orders Found with orderId ${orderId}`})
            }
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
})

/* PLACE A NEW ORDER */
router.post('/new', (req, res) => {

    let {userId, products} = req.body;
    console.log(userId, products)
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: `req.body` is `undefined` by default, you need to use a parser middleware, [more details](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.body)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()) // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

I figured out that this code needs to be used before specifying route path.

Answer (score 60):

**Here is the solution...yayyy!!**

No need to install body-parser.

try this:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

And specify it before your routes like:

**(sequence really matters here!)**

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', Anyroute)
```

Comment: Aaaaaah, thank you!  I was doing the app.use(express.json()) after specifying my routes, and so none of my routes had access to it.  Thank you for bolding that ORDER MATTERS!!

Comment: @AndrewEinhorn glad to help :)

Comment: Oh man you are a life saver <3.

Comment: I only use `app.use(express.json())` in the main file. It's worked!

Answer (score 5):

In my `server.ts` I had

```
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

which gave error message. Changing to

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
```

made it work. Just as OP said in comment, the order must be body-parser first, then path to routes.

Answer (score 3):

You might be missing `bodyParser`:

`const bodyParser = require('body-parser')`

`app.use(bodyParser.json()) // for parsing application/json`

Comment: I don't need to use body parser anymore since express comes bundled with that functionality now.

Comment: After Express 4.16+, we don't need `body-parser` again because now included in the default Express package. Thanks. https://expressjs.com/en/changelog/4x.html

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you pass your data as **raw** and **JSON** as shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: The problem was in the sequence of the code in app.js)

Answer (score 3):

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

The express `urlencoded()` function is a built-in middleware function in Express. It parses incoming requests with `urlencoded` payloads and is based on `body-parser`.

Answer (score 1):

You should `app.use(express.json())` before `app.use(router)`. The order of middleware matters.

Answer (score 1):

Add these line after your models' declaration in index.js

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

app.use(express.json());          add this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem using:

```js
app.use(express.json())
```

Over routes

Answer (score 0):

Add the following middleware

```
// middlewares
app.use(express.json)
app.use(cors)
```

Comment: Forgot to call `json`?

Answer (score 0):

The order of writing middleware matters, i guess.
Previously, this is how my code was:

```
app.use(authRouter); 
app.use(express.json());
```

After facing the error i changed it to this:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(authRouter);
```

then it was working fine.